# Question about LC Filter - Critical Inductance Lc

Tags: capacitor, inductance, passive-filter

In the following screenshot from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gAKtYzXk0M&list=PLvHm1wcxZ2OwRDKVJy85xSJ6XNUxH6XXy&index=24):

[image: Screenshot from Video showing Critical Inductance derivation]

Why in the proof to find critical inductance, \$L_C\$, is the following equation used:

$$ I_{dc} = |I_{ac}|_\mathrm{(peak)} $$

Answer (score 0):

The critical L is chosen to get critical damping when XL=R at \$\omega_0=R/L\$. Not 3L